# `ref` vs. `mutable` assignment operator using F#

Tags: f#, mutable, assignment-operator, ref

Consider the following code:

```
let mutable a = 0.
let b = ref 0.

a <- // works
  printfn "%A" a
  4. + 8.

b := // does not work
  printfn "%A" a
  4. + 8.

b := ( // works
  printfn "%A" a
  4. + 8. )
```

Why does the ref assignment operator (:=) have a different behaviour than the mutable assignment operator (<-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the other answers...

More elaborate expressions are allowed within assignments, so long as the final expression is one of several allowed forms. See [section 6.4.9](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597464) of the spec. This allows complex assignments such as:

```
let x =
  let rec gcd a = function
    | 0 -> a
    | b -> gcd b (a % b)
  gcd 10 25
```

The compiler moves `gcd` to a private member, but nesting it within the assignment allows for tighter scoping. Function arguments, on the other hand, are more restricted. They don't create a new scope (that I'm aware of) and you can't define functions, for example, as part of the expression.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate on this one: "They don't create a new scope (that I'm aware of) and you can't define functions, for example, as part of the expression."? An example would be the best as I am not sure that I understand.

Comment: I just mean you can't pass everything after `let x =` in my example above as a function argument. Function arguments require simpler expressions. This explains why `:=`, which is a function, and `=`/`<-`, which are assignment operators, behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

I can only give a partial answer.

`:=` is defined in terms of `<-` in FSharp.Core\prim-types.fs:

```
let (:=) x y = x.contents <- y
```

In your example

```
b := // does not work
  printfn "%A" a
  4. + 8.
```

`printfn "%A" a` seems to be interpreted as `y`, which cannot be assigned to the int ref cell (wrong type). By grouping the whole expression with `( ... )`, `y` now also contains `4. + 8.`. Maybe the two operators behave differently, because `<-` seems to be an intrinsic operator (i.e. part of the language, not the library).

Comment: But I would definitely expect the "<-" operator to work in an exactly same manner as ":=", no matter what the operators actually are. So they should either both fail or both succeed. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

`:=` is a function (try (:=);; in FSI) which has a type : `'a ref -> 'a -> unit`

So

```
b := // does not work
  printfn "%A" a
  4. + 8.
```

is being parsed as because of the infix call parsing rule:

```
(:=) b (printfn "%A" a)
4. + 8.
```

Which is invalid as par the (:=) function type. 
Other example:

```
let c = 10 + 
            11 
            12
```

c would be 12 here

Comment: But this doesn't explain, why the "infix call parsing rule", as you call it, does not apply to `<-` (and `=` for that matter), does it? I still believe the different behavior is due to the (sensible) distinction between built-in and custom-defined operators.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the inbuilt operators like <- seems to have different parsing rule. In this case <- seems to take the result of complete block where as functions rules are same for all functions. I prefer to call := as function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a discrepancy in the indentation-sensitive parser rather than anything specifically to do with those operators.